# Rsync, logging the names of files sent

Tags: rsync

I'm sending files using `rsync` from server A to B. Server `B` has limited storage, so once the files are sent, they are copied and deleted. So using `rsync's` `--ignore-existing` won't work in this case. I was wondering if there is any way to log names of file I've sent, using `rsync`, so I can save the names in a file and use `--exclude-from`

Comment: This sounds like a complicated way to do this.  You might consider storing each batch in a separate directory. Once the directory is copied, delete it and start sending the next directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the rsync documentation? Reading CLI tool documentation should always be your first line of research in situations like these.

This is all laid out very clearly in the rsync man page:

```
--log-file=FILE
              This option causes rsync to log what it is doing to a file.  This is similar to the logging that a daemon  does,
              but  can  be  requested  for the client side and/or the server side of a non-daemon transfer.  If specified as a
              client option, transfer logging will be enabled with a default format of "%i %n%L".  See  the  --log-file-format
              option if you wish to override this.

              Here’s a example command that requests the remote side to log what is happening:

                rsync -av --remote-option=--log-file=/tmp/rlog src/ dest/

              This is very useful if you need to debug why a connection is closing unexpectedly.

       --log-file-format=FORMAT
              This  allows  you  to  specify  exactly what per-update logging is put into the file specified by the --log-file
              option (which must also be specified for this option to have any effect).   If  you  specify  an  empty  string,
              updated files will not be mentioned in the log file.  For a list of the possible escape characters, see the "log
              format" setting in the rsyncd.conf manpage.

              The default FORMAT used if --log-file is specified and this option is not is ’%i %n%L’.
```